# Disable Checkbox with selection on Dropdown

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown and a checkbox inside a datatable in the xhtml file. The dropdown has L, C, UV and various other selections. When L is selected for example, I want the checkbox to be disabled.

Here is the relevant xhtml code for the dropdown and checkbox:

```
<r2i4:selectForClass itemClass="VehicleGenericType" value="#{vc.vehicleGenericType}" rendered="#{vc.crudState == null || vc.crudState == 'CREATE'}"
    valueChangedListener="#{vehicleCategory.vehicleDropdownChange">
    <f:selectItems value="#{vehicleCategory.vehicleChanged}" />
    <p:ajax />
</r2i4:selectForClass>

<f:facet name="input">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="departmental" value="#{vc.isDepartmental}" rendered="#{vc.crudState == null || vc.crudState == 'CREATE'}" 
    disabled="#{vehicleCategory.vehicleChanged eq 'L'}"/>
</f:facet>
```

In the bean, I have the following code:

```
public void vehicleDropdownChange(ValueChangeEvent e) {
        if(e.getNewValue().equals("L")) {
        }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: maybe it's useful to complete your ajax definition: <p:ajax event="change" update="yourCheckBoxID" />

Comment: @BlueOcean I read somewhere that if I am using valueChangedListener, I should not use ajax, and vice versa. If I was using ajax, how will the bean code look? Thanks.

Comment: backing bean does not change. yes if you use valueChangeListener as soon as the value changes, it  will pass to your backing bean. but there is a point. you have another component in UI that depends on your change. so I think you should use p:ajax and force it to check checkbox enability on each change with "update" option. did you try that? what was the result?

Comment: @BlueOcean I added the ajax definition you commented but when selecting L on the dropdown (or anything else), it doesn't disable the departmental checkbox. I have left the backing bean and everything else the same as you said too. These controls are inside a dataTable, so will this affect it?

Comment: The last thing I can say is use some boolean value. make it true in backing bean in your vehicleDropdownChange method and make sure that it's changing as you expected. then in your xhtml use some simpler code like  disabled="#{vehicleCategory.YourBooleanValue}". I hope it helps

Comment: @BlueOcean Ah - okay. Will you have an example where you can show me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52203/discussion-between-k-honda-and-blue-ocean)

Answer (score 1):

Try code below:

```
<r2i4:selectForClass itemClass="VehicleGenericType" value="#{vc.vehicleGenericType}" rendered="#{vc.crudState == null || vc.crudState == 'CREATE'}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{vehicleCategory.vehicleChanged}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update="departmental" listener="#{vehicleCategory.vehicleDropdownChange} />
</r2i4:selectForClass>

<f:facet name="input">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="departmental" value="#{vc.isDepartmental}" rendered="#{vc.crudState == null || vc.crudState == 'CREATE'}" 
    disabled="#{vehicleCategory.disable}"/>
</f:facet>


public void vehicleDropdownChange(ValueChangeEvent e) {
        if ( .. ) { disable = true }
}
```

it should worked here .

Comment: Will I have to create a disable method in the backing bean? As I have a red line under disable in the vehicleDropdownChange method. Thanks

Comment: it's a variable in your bean with setter and getter. private boolean disable

Comment: I tried mate, but didn't work since the server doesn't get updated with anything. My only way is to try it with javascript of some kind so it can be done on client side... What do you think?

Comment: I suspect there is some confusion with vc and vehicleCategory and bean. sorry but I have no idea. hope someone else help you :-)